# Will I still get an LTE speed if I connect my non LTE smartphone to an LTE pocket wifi?

Tags: lte

So you have an LTE wifi dongle for example and you will connect your non lte smart phone on it. Will you still get it's LTE speed capability?

Answer (score 1):

Like you can't drive to the speed of a F1 race car with your non F1 car, even if on a race track, the smart phone can't use LTE speed if it isn't LTE compatible.

Comment: But as far as I know you can still connect to the LTE device even though you have a non lte phone. Right? So what if the LTE dongle reaches 100mbs speed and I connected my phone on it which is only capable of 50mbs bandwidth will I still get the maximum 50mbs?

Comment: Your LTE dongle may be 3G / UMTS compatible, or another bandwidth, and as such your are in fact not int LTE. You should be able to use the full capabilities of your phone, but below LTE max speed.

Comment: But in terms of internet speed like downloading which one is faster an LTE wifi dongle or an H+ dongle using my device to download which is also only H+ capable?

Comment: or better in terms of connectivity?

Comment: If you are connecting your phone to the LTE-wifi dongle using wifi, it does not matter if your phone is LTE or 3G or whatever. In your scenario with the 100Mbps LTE link and 50Mbps wifi link, yes your phone will reach a maximum of 50Mbps.

Answer (score 1):

You can surely connect your non-LTE device to LTE wifi dongle. However the speed will really depend on 2 things.

1. LTE wifi dongle : Normally operators throttle speeds of LTE dongles. So you may not always get full truput as claimed by the operator.
2. Your Phone Wifi capability (802.11??)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have the following:

```
 - A non-LTE smartphone with wifi
 - A dongle with LTE and wifi
```

You should be able to connect your phone to the dongle with wifi and use the LTE connection. The overall speed of your connection will depend on the attainable speeds of your LTE and wifi connections.

Let's assume that you are in a good LTE coverage area that is not congested. Furthermore, let's assume the operator has built out the network with the latest features and has plenty of spectrum available. You may be able to get 40-50Mbps, for example (between the dongle and network).

Now, for the wifi link between your phone and the dongle, it is a very short distance and the two devices are relatively stationary with respect to each other. 100Mbps+ should be attainable with wifi, so your LTE link is the limiting factor.

In short, the answer is yes, you can get LTE speeds with your setup. However, there are many factors that come into play and LTE is not always fast. The best that you can do is to ensure that your wifi link is performing optimally as there is not much you can do about the LTE link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LTE wifi dongle, but you will need either:

1. Separate subscription for using the LTE wifi dongle (i.e. a new SIM with subscription to LTE services). Most operators have different configuration for LTE APN and you need to configure your SIM in the wifi dongle if not already done.
2. Use your current SIM from non-LTE phone and insert it into wifi dongle, in that case you need to check your agreement with the operator to see if that is allowed and also check if existing SIM has access to LTE network otherwise you will end up with no internet connection.

There are more conditions like LTE coverage and Wifi packet drop rate to be considered to get accurate information about the throughput that you will be able to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will. You are likely to get speeds on your wifi phone that are close( slightly less) to what your LTE  connection provides you.

Think of  LTE  as just a   fat data pipe to your wifi dongle. For all intends and purposes, thats all LTE does From your dongle to your  Wifi-connected device,  Wifi acts as another data pipe. The pipe with lower  capacity ( bandwidth) will limit the  data  speed you get.

Now, wifi  speeds are  orders of magnitude greater that current  LTE ( 4G  speed) . that is  1300 Mb to 300Mb for  wifi ,  compared to 7Mbs to 10 Mbs for lte.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You will be on WiFi which may have the same speed as if you were on LTE. The LTE connection is only between the LTE hotspot and the carrier. You and the hotspot will be talking on WiFi only.

Answer (score 0):

There are two factors deciding the speed you will get -

- your pocket wifi's LTE capabilities
- your phone's wifi capabilities

In most cases, your pocket wifi will give you LTE speeds over wifi which your phone should also be able to support and you should get good speeds with lesser battery consumption on phone.

Answer (score 0):

The connection is over wifi and not dependent upon devices Cellular capability